# Http server on SOCK_STREAM - when to end connection?

Tags: c, linux, sockets, http, cgi

I am currently writing a server http on linux that is supposed to serve GET and POST queries. My question is:
    - When should I shutdown the connection with a certain client? Instantly after sending response? Or should I wait on socket to get another query to serve?
   - How to implement POST queries so that the server stays the most generic as it is possible? Should I use CGI? If so - how?

I hope I am specific enough,
Thanks!

Comment: what does the spec say ?

Comment: So, if I understand it correctly. Server and client pass meta info about the connection in Connection header, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the real time HTTP implementations(I'm talking about the HTTP GET) there used to be a part in the header that says about the persistent connections. You can find this in the HTTP specifications too. In case persistence is set to true the server would not close the connection until a timeout. This is to speedup the browsing in the cases where the client may want another resource that is dependent/related to the current query. For example you may request for a web page and that web page may contain references to images or other resources.

You can close the connection as soon as you serve PUT/POST requests.

I hope this link (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_persistent_connection) will give you an insight about this. Most of the HTTP connections are considered as persistent(Note: for a short period of time, say until a timeout) to avoid delays as mentioned above unless it is specified externally.